# Can i use redis along side JpaRepository in the same model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

Hi i just learn to use redis as my secondary database, my code is still for learning purpose, what i trying to do here is, i going to save my data into Postgresql and redis in a same time, but i can't even get my spring boot run, before i code the save function. i got these error :

> Description:
>
> The bean 'stockRepository', defined in
> com.example.demo.repository.StockRepository defined in
> @EnableRedisRepositories declared on
> RedisRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableRedisRepositoriesConfiguration, could
> not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in
> com.example.demo.repository.StockRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication and overriding is
> disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

i just add `@RedisHash(value = "bookStockRedis")` in my model and that happend, here is my model looked like :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = { "id" })
@Table(name = "bookStock")
@RedisHash(value = "bookStockRedis")
public class Stock extends AuditField {

    @Schema(description = "Id merupakan primary key, tipe datanya Long", example = "0", required = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Schema(description = "Warehouse Id yang merupakan Id yang di ambil dari Id di tabel transaksi, di jadikan id warehouse, ber tipe Long", example = "1", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private Long warehouseId;

    @Schema(description = "Kode gudang yang merupakan kode yang di ambil dari transaction code, di jadikan kode gudang virtual", example = "DP/2020/01", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String warehouseCode;

    @Schema(description = "Tanggal transaksi, tanggal di ambil dari tanggal transaksi", example = "1", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private Date transactionDate;

    @Schema(description = "Trans Id yang merupakan Id yang di ambil dari Id di tabel transaksi, di jadikan id transaksi, ber tipe Long", example = "1", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private Long transId;

    @Schema(description = "Kode transaksi yang merupakan kode yang di ambil dari transaction code setiap transaksi, di jadikan trans number", example = "DP/2020/01", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String transNumber;

    @Schema(description = "Product Id yang merupakan Id yang di ambil dari Id di tabel master product", example = "1", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private Long productId;

    @Schema(description = "Kode Product yang merupakan kode yang di ambil dari master product", example = "MCM-508", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String productCode;

    @Schema(description = "Jumlah qty yang akan di kurang atau di tambah, bisa berupa value plus (tidak perlu tanda minus) untuk menambah stock, bisa berupa value minus (perlu tanda minus) untuk mengurangi stock ketika di jumlahkan", example = "10", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private BigInteger qty;

    @Schema(description = "id dari sebuah branch", example = "1", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private Long branchId;

    @Schema(description = "Kode Branch", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String branchCode;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transTypeId")
    private TransType transType;

}
```

and here is my repository :

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends RevisionRepository<Stock, Long, Integer>, JpaRepository<Stock, Long> {

    @Query(value = "here is manual sql query that is too long since i don't think there is to do with it, i just change it to this string to keep the code simple")
    List<Tuple> findStocktotal();

}
```

as you can see, i use JpaRepository and RevisionRepository to manage my Postgresql database. What do i missed here? or i should clone the model and separate it from JpaRepository one and Redis one?

Comment: split "StockRepository" in two separate interfaces - one for Redis and one for JPA. I see no reason why should you split model. Consider using two different names: @Repository("redisRepo") / @Repository("jpaRepo")

Comment: can you give me complete example? i try to add another repository that extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Stock, Integer> still i got that error

Answer (score 1):

Keep the model as it is.

Have two instances of your repository layer

JPA repository

```java
@Repository("jpaStockRepository")
public interface JpaStockRepository extends JpaRepository<Stock, Long>

    @Query(value = "here is manual sql query that is too long since i don't think there is to do with it, i just change it to this string to keep the code simple")
    List<Tuple> findStocktotal();
}
```

Redis repository

```java
@Repository("redisStockRepository")
public interface RedisStockRepository extends RevisionRepository<Stock, Long, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "query")
    List<Tuple> findStocktotal();

}
```

In your service layer use it like:

```java
@Service
public class StockService {
   
   @Autowired
   private RedisStockRepository redisStockRepo;

   @Autowired
   private JpaStockRepository jpaStockRepo;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

In your java config class you are having something like:

```java
@EnableRedisRepositories
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JpaRedisConfiguration {

}
```

update with

```java
@EnableRedisRepositories(repositoryImplementationPostfix="redis")
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryImplementationPostfix="jpa")
public class JpaRedisConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: nope, this is not working, my application still won't start, and i still give me the same error in the first place

Comment: I've updated the response - give it a try :)

Comment: when i add (repositoryImplementationPostfix="jpa") in @EnableJpaRepositories, it give me error "The attribute repositoryImplementationPostfix is undefined for the annotation type EnableJpaAuditing" what did i missed?